# Cannot save hasOne() model relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Visitor model:

```
public function group()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('MyApp\Models\VisitorGroup', 'group_id');
}
```

VisitorGroup model:

```
public function visitors()
{
  return $this->hasMany('MyApp\Models\Visitor');
}
```

So then I'm trying to create some Visitors for a group:

```
$mygroup = VisitorGroup::whereRaw('name LIKE "%mygroup%"')->first();
foreach(range(1, 10) as $i)
{
  $v = Visitor::create(array('name' => 'Homer simpson'));
  $v->group()->save($mygroup); // HERE trying to add this visitor to the group
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The relationship kind to weird to me. A visitor could be more than one group and A group could have many visitor, is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `BelongsTo` has no `save()` method. However it has an `associate()` method which is probably what you're looking for. Not that you have to explicitly save the model afterwards:

```
$v = Visitor::create(array('name' => 'Homer simpson'));
$v->group()->associate($mygroup);
$v->save();
```

---

Or you could just set the foreign key manually when creating to save db queries:

```
$v = Visitor::create(array('name' => 'Homer simpson', 'group_id' => $mygroup->id));
```

---

Or the probably most elegant way:

```
$mygroup->visitors()->create(array('name' => 'Homer simpson'));
```